# How do I render Dynamic Content in HTML with NodeJS without a Template Engine

Tags: html, node.js, express, server-side-rendering

I bought an HTML website template from ThemeForest which I'd like to use for my project. 
I would like to build this as a NodeJS application preferably with the Express framework. I now understand that 
there are Template Engines like Pug which don't seem to be right for me since my files are fully built as HTML markup.

So how else do I get my persistent application data e.g Names, lists and Images rendered into my HTML the same way we do with PHP embeded in HTML like :

```
<div class='display-name'> <?php echo $_my_data['name'];?> <div>
```

Currently, I have been making Ajax Requests to the NodeJS server on page-load that returns JSON data which I then append to the respective elements. I feel like there is a better way to do this. Any pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: Other templating engines like mustache or handlebars can work on HTML without changing the overall structure.

Comment: Alright thank, let me take a look at that.

Comment: @Sirko,  I am looking at Handlebars right now, it does the rendering that I want but again, it seems as the rendering is done on the client-side which suggests I still have to make an XMLHttp Request to fetch the data. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm not aware that handlebars would be bound to client-side. You could also execute the compile process within express. There even seem to be middleware-plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Comment: OK, I'll take a deeper look

Comment: I have taken an in-depth look into handlebars and yes, it absolutely solves my problem.  By using ```express-handlebars```, I am able to render my app-data on the serverside and only display it while everything is set. Thanks.